# docker rmi --force giving error on commandline

Tags: docker

When I give this command

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images -a --filter=dangling=true -q)
```

Some of it gets deleted and it stops abruptly with this message

> Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 01b2323cdc
> (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container
> 7e23232beaa

Then I gave

```
$ docker rmi --force $(docker images -a --filter=dangling=true -q)
```

also this

```
$ docker rmi -f $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

But I get error

> "docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument. See 'docker rmi --help'.
> Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...] Remove one or more
> images

How to use --force correctly in this scenario?

Comment: You get this message because command substitution returns nothing

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `--force` at all.  I believe the only thing it overrides is allowing deleting images that are still being used by containers.  On modern Docker, `docker system prune` will clean up both stopped containers and unused images without needing `--force` (or a command substitution).

Comment: Have you tried  `docker image rm -f $(docker images -a --filter=dangling=true -q) ` or simply `docker image prune` ?

Comment: prune is a different command and it works. `$ docker rmi -f $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)` this gives same result.